# after_update callback issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, sql-update

I have a model A which has association with another model Company. So, I call it as `A.find(5).companies`

I want to do something in `after_update` callback of A. I add some companies in A.find(5).companies and want to know which companies got added in the callback. But in after_update callback, how can I get the list of companies in A.find(5).companies before the update?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the `on_create` callback of model `Company`. Whenever a new company is added, you can see value of A from this and do your task.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a logic using the created_at and updated_at timings .

Once you will fire after_update callback for model A the updated_at filed of the table will be updated and you can get the list of companies  where created_at time is later then the updated at of model A.

Comment: The new companies added are added from an existing table, hence are created already. So, created_at won't work

Comment: so is there any other table also where you are adding the new table or how you are managing the new companies?

Comment: New companies are added to Companies table but here, I am dealing with the old companies.

Answer (score 0):

.. in your controller.. when updating a model with accepts_nested_attributes_for

```
def update
  a.assign_attributes(params[:a])
  was_changed = a.companies.any?{|c| c.changed?} 
  a.save
end
```